# nginx proxy in front of another nginx webserver > get correct IPs

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a nginx reverse-proxy (server A) running in front of another nginx server (B).

However, A doesn't seem to pass the IPs correctly to server B.

Even though I have

```
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

these lines in my config.

I know for Apache you simply load the RPAF-module.

Is there something similar for nginx ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice overview of modules here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules
Specifically you need this: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealIpModule

Comment: Cheers, this fixed the issue for both logs and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Some more detail would be helpful on what you mean by "doesn't pass the IPs" - where you're seeing the wrong IP, and what you're expecting.

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you're probably seeing the reverse proxy's address instead of the client's address in the logs - you can alter your log format to show the contents of the `X-Forwarded-For` header (the example below is a tweak to the default combined format):

```
log_format proxied_combined '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                            '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                            '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log logdir/access.log proxied_combined;
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, both logs as PHP ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] for example) give the proxy's address.